# Production settings file for log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

Here is my current log4j settings file. Are these settings ideal for production use or is there something I should remove/tweak or change? I ask because I was getting all my threads being hung due to log4j blocking. I checked my open file descriptors I was only using 113.

```
# ***** Set root logger level to WARN and its two appenders to stdout and R.
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout, R

# ***** stdout is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
# ***** stdout uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# ***** Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

# ***** R is set to be a RollingFileAppender.
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=logs/myapp.log
# ***** Max file size is set to 100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=102400KB
# ***** Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
# ***** R uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %d %c - %m%n


#set httpclient debug levels
log4j.logger.org.apache.component=ERROR,stdout 
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire=ERROR,stdout 
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=ERROR,stdout 
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.client.protocol=ERROR,stdout
```

UPDATE***
Adding thread dump sample from all my threads (100)

```
"pool-1-thread-5" - Thread t@25
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED on org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger@1d45a585 owned by: pool-1-thread-35
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:201)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:302)
```

Answer (score 34):

Log4j 1.2 is vulnerable to [deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7157507/log4j-deadlock-occuring-between-logger-and-appender) when `toString()` produces nested logging.

See old aged still unresolved issues like [Log4J can create deadlock conditions (concurrent package donation)](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24159) and [Deadlock with RollingFileAppender](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41214).

It also has performance-killing lock synchronization issues under heavy concurrent load.
Like [Category callAppenders synchronization causes java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50213) and  [Move org.apache.log4j.Category to reentrant read/write locks](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51047).

Even [AsyncAppender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112560/how-to-use-asyncappender-in-log4j) is not free of excessive locks:
[AsyncAppender.doAppend() does not need to be synchronized](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51048) and [Deadlock in 1.2.15 caused by AsyncAppender and ThrowableInformation classes](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46878). Also beware of [AsyncAppender overflow](http://glueclue.blogspot.com/2007/01/log4j-asyncappender-is-not-always_31.html).

One caveat is to always constrain root category level to at least INFO or higher. This would prevent logging calls from acquiring unnecessary locks mentioned in the above issues. Just limiting appender threshold is not sufficient as it is taken into account later. See [explanation with publish/subscribe analogy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074349/603516):

> To answer your question about how threshold interacts with category,
>   basically think of it is as a publish/subscribe. The category sets
>   what is published by the logger, the threshold sets the subscription
>   level of the appender.

Nested categories of interest can be individually given lower priorities if needed.

Answer (score 2):

%F:%L has serious performance impact. Although I don't see how they'd cause locking, I'd consider omitting them for production.

Comment: Agreed. Instead, compile your code with debug information and you will get the line numbers in stack traces when errors occur.

Comment: yes using %c which prints package and class name in place of %F:%L should be a good

Answer (score 2):

Are you creating a Logger for each class using the standard `private static final Logger  logger = Logger.getLogger(Foo.class);` where Foo is the class in which the logger is declared?  If you only have 1 Logger instance in your entire application, there could be some contention if there is a lot of logging.

Answer (score 0):

This looks normal.  I don't see how this alone could cause log4j blocking.  Maybe you could post a thread dump of your issue?