# log4j debug messages not showing in console despite isDebugEnabled being true

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using the following code within my project to log debug messages with log4j

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class)
// ...
if(LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOG.debug("my log message");
}
```

I can confirm that my log4j configuration is correct by adding a break point at the line where the debug message is written, i.e. `LOG.isDebugEnabled()` does return `true`.
Interestingly, my debug message does not show up in the console of my IDE (IntelliJ), however when changing `LOG.debug()` to `LOG.info()`, the info message is logged as expected.

Any ideas what I should be looking for in order to find out what's going wrong here?

**EDIT:** here's my log4j.properties file

```
log4j.appender.Stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%-5p [%d{dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss}] %C{1} - %m [thread: %t]\n
log4j.appender.Stdout.threshold=info

log4j.appender.StandaloneFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.StandaloneFile.File=logs/standalone.log
log4j.appender.StandaloneFile.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.StandaloneFile.MaxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.StandaloneFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.StandaloneFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%d{dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss}] %C{1} - %m [thread: %t]\n
log4j.appender.StandaloneFile.threshold=info

log4j.rootLogger=info, Stdout, StandaloneFile
log4j.logger.com.myPacke.package1=info, Stdout, StandaloneFile

log4j.logger.com.myPacke.package2=DEBUG
```

Comment: can you add log4j.properties ? maybe you're missing an appender...

Comment: Sorry, thought we would not need this, since `isDebugEnabled` returned `true` already, but of course, you are right. I have updated the question.

Comment: isDebugEnabled() is not enough, you may have filters (as you indeed have). See StephenC comment on baraky answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
log4j.appender.Stdout.threshold=info
```

Should be:

```
log4j.appender.Stdout.threshold=debug
```

You just set the console threshold to be info, so you're not getting debug level logs.

Be aware you also set the RollingFileAppender threshold to info as @Stephen C commented.

Comment: +1 - Debug logging is enabled (from the root logger down) ... but both of his appenders are filtering out log events below "INFO".

Comment: Ouch... of course! One should think that naming a config parameter `threshold` should be obvious... I just did not notice it :( Thanks a lot! After an additional read of [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119883/log4j-what-is-threshold) I now actually understand what exactly is going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your configuration has below appender...We have used log4j.xml so i am adding from xml

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="info" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="logfile" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="log/dcm_migration.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="false" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d  %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```