# Wildfly 10 not showing debug messages

Tags: java, debugging, logging, log4j, wildfly

I'm testing my ear application on the container and I need to see some debugging messages I spread on my application. I'm using `slf4j-api` with `log4j` as logging framework.

During my test phase (out of the container) all logging was working perfectly, so the configuration is fine. But now I've deployed the application with the same configuration but my messages are not showing. Here is my log4j's config:

```
#rootLogger config
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, console

#appender config
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console..threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} [%t] %p %l - %m%n

# Log JDBC bind parameter runtime arguments
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=INFO

#application logger config
log4j.logger.ar.edu.unt.sigea=DEBUG, console
```

As I said, when I run my `@Test` methods, all my `logger.debug()` messages are shown correctly, but now that I'm running on the container with the same configuration, no debug message is shown.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086818/log4j-debug-messages-not-showing-in-console-despite-isdebugenabled-being-true) and added the line `log4j.appender.console..threshold=DEBUG` as suggested by the answer but didn't work.

I'm deploying on **Wildfly-10.0.0.Final** Application Server and I'm using this logging dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing? Where should I look for? Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: have you tried changing the logging level at wildfly? `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` and find the tag `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">`. change the loggers you want.

Comment: Thanks @Apostolos, I'm reading the documentation, if you know right now how to configure the `standalone-full.xml` (that's the file I'm using) just post it as an answer.

Comment: i think it's the same thing. if this worked for you, please let me post it as an answer to accept it. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at [this Wildfly Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration) I realized that my `log4j.properties` file was located in a wrong place: it was in a submodule of my project and must be in the `META-INF` folder of the EAR module.

By default, Wildfly takes the deployment's logging configuration, so no extra configuration is needed in `standalone.xml` (or `standalone-full.xml` depending on what profile are you using, which is my case).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the log4j binding unless you want to use your own log4j configuration. From the configuration file it looks like you're just using console appender which is already provided by the WildFly logging subsystem.

All you need to do to see debug messages with your current configuration is to remove the `log4j.properties` from your deployment and remove the `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12` dependency from your pom. Then you can use the logging subsystem to configure logging and turn on/off debug logging. If you use CLI or the web console you can change logging levels without restarting the server.

To add a debug level and change the default `console-handler` level to `DEBUG`. The following two CLI commands are all you need to configure debug logging.

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=ar.edu.unt.sigea:add(level=DEBUG)
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level, value=DEBUG)
```

Comment: This does the trick thanks! And to remove use: /subsystem=logging/logger=ar.edu.unt.sigea:remove

Answer (score 1):

## switch the log level to DEBUG on console

```
{wildfly}/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level,value=DEBUG)

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:write-attribute(name=level,value=DEBUG)
```

## switch it back to whatever it was initial configuration (here it is INFO)

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level,value=INFO)

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:write-attribute(name=level,value=INFO)
```

From: https://gist.github.com/lfryc/aae879ceb5534292e150