# difference between root logger level and threshold in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have below log4j configuration.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CA
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.CA.Threshold = WARN
```

What is the difference between root log level `DEBUG` and Threshold `WARN`?

Threshold should always be greater than root log level?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The root level sets a global floor; the threshold applies to a specific appender. So yes, the threshold needs to be greater than the root level to be meaningful.

[Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119883/log4j-what-is-threshold) for more information on the relationship of loggers, appenders, and reporting levels.