# concurrent log4j

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, concurrency, log4j

I have my own logging engine which writes the logs on a separate thread with a blocking queue. For the sake of using "standard software" I am thinking about switching to log4j.

I don't want my highly concurrent software to be slowed down by log commands that write everything to disk as some as the command is called. Can log4j be used as a dumpster instead?

Comment: logj4 might not be your best bet, if you need highly concurrent logging you should go w/ just something like a concurrent linked queue (or blocking) and a dedicated polling thread. Logging by default blocks hard (if you need to log for real). If you need even higher concurrency you can use a queue per thread (and still poll each queue by a separate one)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13144054/603516 for some links to related log4j locking issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log4j is the logging implementation on most JavaEE app-servers out there, so that's a good advert for its concurrency abilities.

Having said that, I have seen Log4j 1.2 deadlock under high load conditions. A bit of investigation highlighted some scarily bad synchronization in the source code. Apparently, this was fixed in Log4j 1.3, although development on this has slowed or stopped altogether - I get the feeling much of the source was unsalvageable.

However, if you're free to choose, then you should consider [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) instead, the spiritual successor to Log4j. It's a ground-up redesign, and is probably a better option for you.

Comment: Most (all) EE  servers are anything but heavily concurrent, simply they are not. Saying that after 2 days+night battles vs tomcat data races. Note. as "heavily concurrent" I assume 32+ cores that don't get starved.

Answer (score 3):

Check out log4j's [asynchronous appender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/AsyncAppender.html), it buffers log messages ad passes them on to appenders using a separate thread. It might be that you decide the log4j async appender is not appropriate [(here are some complaints about it)](http://glueclue.blogspot.com/2007/01/log4j-asyncappender-is-not-always_31.html), you could always make your own appender.

Comment: I'd not call the impl. highly concurrent at any rate. It's async but not highly concurrent.