# Logging Configuration in Logback + SL4J + JBoss EAP 6.0

Tags: logging, jboss7.x, slf4j, logback

I am trying to use Logback with SL4J in a Web Application that is deployed on JBoss EAP 6.0. As per [Logback and Jboss 7 - don't work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518687/logback-and-jboss-7-dont-work-together). However, even this is not working! The application seems to ignore my logback.xml that is in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder.

Comment: How did you know that your logback.xml was ignored? Some warning or error log will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you add a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` to exclude the sfl4j dependencies from the server and provide your own? Also is there a reason you need to use the logback.xml and you can't use the logging subsystem configuration?

Comment: Sorry for not having responded. There were other issues that came up meanwhile. @Jintian Whatever configuration that I had given like new appender etc. were ignored completely. @James I have included the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should try using log4j. I remember following this tutorial a while back and it worked.
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-log/using-log4j-with-jboss-as-7-and-wildfly

You need to use exclusions because JBOSS comes with a lot of modules/jars preinstalled. 
Hope this helps!