# Logback not working with JBoss EAP 6.1

Tags: maven, jboss, logback

I have a maven web application in which I am using logback and JBoss EAP 6.1 as server. The problem is that when I deploy it on server, my logback.xml is ignored and logback's default configuration is used which prints on console instead of my log file. Logging works fine if I deploy my application on tomcat.

I have put logback.xml in src/main/resources.

Found similar question at - [Logging Configuration in Logback + SL4J + JBoss EAP 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374891/logging-configuration-in-logback-sl4j-jboss-eap-6-0)
and
[Logback and Jboss 7 - don't work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518687/logback-and-jboss-7-dont-work-together)
but no use...

Comment: not gonna work bro, i've been trying here for about 2 weeks, nothing I do works

Comment: Hey Abdul..Find my solution below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forgot to share the solution earlier..here it is -

We need to add following lines in jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
</exclusions>
```

So the entire file looks like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding 
            some dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>

    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

If you have a maven project, you can put this file at -

```
<project>/webapp/META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml
```

Now logging will work fine.

Comment: I've been trying to use a jboss-deployment-structure.xml but that's not working either... let me try the one you provided and see what happens. I'll update you with results

Comment: nope... still not working for me, thank you for the reply though

Comment: I see, I added two subdeployments and I think that did the trick! thanks for the tips

Answer (score 2):

First, thanks to @popeye

Climbing on to what @popeye has well defined, here are my 2 cents

Location of '`jboss-deployment-structure.xml`' : `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Hey Server please don't add these dependencies. I don't need them. 
                                 I have mine in my application dependencies -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.ext" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="com.oracle" />
            <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Now, `logback.xml` is in action. yo!

- why is this needed - `<module name="com.oracle" />` ?

This is the name of module of driver you mentioned in JBOSS `standalone.xml`

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
            <datasources>
                <datasource><!-- your configurations --></datasource>
                  <drivers>
                    <driver name="ojdbc6-11.2.0.4" module="com.oracle">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                  </drivers>
            </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

Note that this is for JBOSS server to Database communication.
[Even if you have `ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.jar` in your *project/lib* you need this configuration ]

**How** did you come up with this name 'com.oracle'? Is that a standard ?
**No** . This is the struture of folder I created on server
Look at this SO post here - [Xmlparserv2 error while application deployed in jboss, Installing Oracle ojdbc module in JBoss for Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370270/xmlparserv2-error-while-application-deployed-in-jboss)  *'How to create a Oracle module in JBOSS'*

Also note not to confuse this one with the dependency that you might add in your project `pom.xml`.
ie: this one

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope> <!-- to exclude from WEB-INF/lib -->
            </dependency>
```

The above project dependency is needed for you to write the Java code, get it compiled,
and also during runtime, for your code to communicate to the driver.

- why is this needed - `<module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" slot="main" />` ?

Otherwise you might get an **error** to get a jndi datasource set on JBoss in your Spring application.
So that's a dependency. Don't forget to add the jar as well in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.ironjacamar</groupId>
            <artifactId>ironjacamar-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```