# Log back not able to find the configuration file (logback.xml)

Tags: java, logging, java-ee-6, slf4j, logback

I'm trying to use logback as the logging framework for my new project.

I placed the logback.xml in `main\resources\logback.xml`.

These are the contents of `logback.xml` file

```
<configuration debug="true">

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
  <file>D:/logbacklog.log</file>
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
    <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
  </layout>
 </appender> 


    <logger name="com.myproject" level="ALL"/>


    <root level="debug">
       <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
     </root>
 </configuration>
```

However, logs I enter do get printed in the console (may be it's using the default configuration).

I extracted my WAR file and found that it is in `WEB-INF\classes`. I think it's the proper place. Any idea why my configuration file is not getting detected ?

PS : I tried making mistakes intentionally in my configuration file (like improper XML format), but still no error was thrown .

This is the Maven dependency for Logback.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the DOCs http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html there is an especific paragraph that states what could cause your issue.

Comment: I read that page. I did not notice anything that solves my problem. Care to point out ?

Comment: So what I would do is copy the configuration from the docs, put in my project and test. If it work I would see whats the difference. Try that.

Comment: The problem is, it does not detect/read the configuration file.

Comment: What application server are you using?

Comment: we are using Jboss AS 7.1

Comment: In Web application, logback.xml don't works, it gets called automatically from somewhere... Please guide... Regards, Neha

Answer (score 0):

JBoss AS helpfully diverts your logging to its own JBoss Log framework. See [Logback and Jboss 7 - don't work together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518687/logback-and-jboss-7-dont-work-together)

On my project, I gave up trying to use Logback (except in tests) and just put up with JBoss logging, because it was able to do everythin we needed.

Answer (score -1):

Just add following dependecy into your pom.xml file,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```