# SLF4J logging with jboss/wildfly 10

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, wildfly, slf4j

I have a Java webapp running in a WildFly 10 server. I used to have the following libraries as Maven dependencies:

```
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>

        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>

        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>

        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
```

I would now like to use wildfly's builtin logging subsystem.

- Which libraries do I need to add to my project(s)?
- How do I configure the default log-category and root logger declared in standalone.xml to log everything from packages "com.mycompany" at level "debug"?
- I'm running the wildfly server as a plugin in my eclipse. By using the console handler, I want the logs to be written to the console of Eclipse

Currently, it isn't working and I'm not sure which of the 3 steps have I have misconfigured. Here's a snippet from standalone.xml:

```
 ...            
        <logger category="com.company">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
 ...
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518687/logback-and-jboss-7-dont-work-together/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have in your `standalone.xml` is correct. However you're including too many slf4j dependencies. slf4j is meant to be a logging facade first. There is no need to include implementation dependencies in your application.

First you'll want to remove the log4j2 dependencies from your pom. Then mark the `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` as `<scope>provided</scope>` as the container already provides that dependency for you. That should be all you need to do.

Comment: It's worth noting that you need to figure out the SLF4J version that WildFly uses. For WildFly 10, it's 1.7.7, you can find the JAR in `modules/system/layers/base/org/slf4j/main/`.

Comment: I don't think that should matter. The slf4j API should be compatible with older and newer 1.7.x versions of the API.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late for the answer, but maybe it helps someone.

Ran into the same problem using WildFly 25.0.0.

Solution:
Create a file in your war archive in folder "META-INF" named "jboss-deployment-structure.xml" and specify which modules should be excluded from the classpath:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <!-- Exclusions allow you to prevent the server from automatically adding some dependencies     -->
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I've written it up here:
https://gist.github.com/BlueSKySec/63006f7cd6bef717af0bae71c1e3a9dc