# JBoss server.log output customization

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, webserver, jboss7.x

I have developed a servlet that outputs the server.log file of my JBoss 7.1 for easier debugging.

What i want to do is to customize the output of JBoss and also display from which war each line of output is generated.

To understand better this is a sample output right now:

[image: server log as a servlet]

What i want is also to output something that will identify from which deployment this output is coming from.

After the URL in each output i noticed a number after the 7001 port that is different for each deployment, but don't know how to associate that with a war file....

Anyone has an idea how i can do that?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I found this on the web http://java.dzone.com/articles/configuring-logging-jboss about configuring JBoss but sadly is for another version. Here it explains how to have log4j create different log files per deployment. That would be the ultimate solution for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it seems (from the content of your logs) you are using System.out.println and System.err.println.

If you switch your logging to slf4j, log4j, commons-logging and of course jboss-logging (thank you James) will be able to see what package you are logging from.

Once you use a proper logging facility you can filter by category by editing configuration file.

Also the logging will show more readable i.e. :

```
05:21:42,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
```

I will assume you are using the standalone configuration in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

You need to find the logging subsystem

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
```

and create a new appender of type periodic-rotating-file-handler:

```
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="APPLOG1">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="applog1.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Then add the filter:

```
         <logger category="com.yourapppackage">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handler name="APPLOG1"/>
        </logger>
```

That should do the work.

If I am not mistaken you can also create appenders and category filters from the administration console and the CLI

Regards

Comment: Just to add you can use JBoss Logging too. That's what the server uses.

Comment: i havent added any logging facility. its the default. and yes i have the standalone installation

Comment: Are those log statements from your application?

Comment: yes, those shown in the pic are System.out and .err statements. But there are also others coming from JBoss like deployment info's, authentication failures etc...

Comment: what i want to do is to capture those .out and .err per war file, because right now i see a bunch of those not knowing from where each output is generated from

Comment: i want to create a similar functionality and calling lets say mydomain.com/mywar/showConsole i will see only the outs of the mywar application

Comment: The only way I see to do something close to what you want is to use a logging facility instead of system.out/err. nobody should be ever using system.out for any serious application (not meaning to be insulting or anything) system.out/err is a very basic logging facility that is not configurable at all.
My response holds a good way to fix your issue, the only difference is that instead of log by mydomain.com/mywar/showConsole you will see something like: 
05:21:42,272 INFO  [com.application.package] YOUR LOG STATEMENT

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. After a lot of thoughts I have created my own Logging facility and I am pretty happy with the result. I will post it as an answer as well when i find some spare time. The result is something like this : 11:35:29,907 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-7001-16) [mywar, JavaMailClass]->Connected to server, Now sending email:.....