# Configure Log4j1.x to log asynchronously through property files

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a large, Spring-based eCommerce framework as a codebase which makes use of pre configured log4j. I can override property values defined in log4j.properties.

I'd like to configure log4j to log asynchronously to console/file, I've attempted to define new/override appenders but am not seeing any output to console and am unsure why.

Is it possible to wrap current log4j into asynchronous calls?

Comment: As far as i know log4j 1.x does not support async logging.

Comment: It does although not to the same degree as v2

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/a/15121718/1140748

Comment: @sion You are correct. I'm sorry. I didn't know that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use AsyncAppender in log4j?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112560/how-to-use-asyncappender-in-log4j)