# How eliminate additional info when executing Solr full import in Java

Tags: java, solr, data-import

I'm getting the following logs during solr import via Java routine.

INFO: Creating new http client, config:maxConnections=128&maxConnectionsPerHost=32&followRedirects=false

This is the import code im using,

```
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(Base_Url);

ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set("command", "full-import");
params.set("clean", "true");
params.set("commit", "true");
params.set("optimize", "true");

QueryRequest request = new QueryRequest(params);
request.setPath("/dataimport");


    server.request(request);
```

Is there a way to make this go away. I've done a lot of research already. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to avoid the log entries? If that's the case, try configure logging to  (how depends on the logging library you're using) not show anything below WARNING.

Comment: Hi, I'm using log4j. I've used the following configuration in the past log4j.rootLogger=OFF
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=solrimptlog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=1000KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10

Comment: Try using `log4j.appender.R.threshold=warn` to only get messages of severity WARN or worse. There's also a bit of information available in [Production settings file for log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537870/production-settings-file-for-log4j/) about possible deadlocks, but I'm not familiar enough with log4j to say anything useful about that.

Comment: Thanks. Tried the above but still didn't work. My hunch is httpsolrserver was already deprecated. Trying to mess around with httpsolrclient to do the import but didn't find an example yet..