# Log4j - Log only specified method to file

Tags: log4j

Using log4j to log specific events (DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL..) having specified in the properties file to log only DEBUG i still end up having other error messages logged in the file. Is there a way to tell log4j to log only specific events to a file?

Thank You.

Comment: post your properties file and we maybe help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read on [appender additivity](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html). You must set it to false. A similar question was asked [before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041548/log4j-appender-threshold-and-category).

Relevant code snippet:

```
<category name="org.quartz" additivity="false">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
</category>
```

Version for a `properties` file:

```
log4j.additivity.org.quartz = false
```